# aes encryption in html5

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

I am developing an application in HTML5. I want to store the Password in encrypted form in database.

Can anybody please suggest me the code for doing the encryption?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It is a server-side problem and you have to solve it at server side. HTML5 is just a markup language which helps you create your web interface, which is a client-side thing. All major server-side web development technologies such as PHP, JavaEE, ASP.NET and RoR have libraries to employ popular encryption schemas like AES-256.

Answer (score 0):

Use one of PHP's [Cryptography Extensions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.crypto.php). I would recommend the [Hash Function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php).
As Arash has already stated you can't use HTML 5 for this, HTML is only used for layout (i.e. it can't process user input)